# div containing image not responding to hover

Tags: html, css

I have two `divs` - one containing an image and one containing a menu bar.  The idea is to hover over the `#changeLayer` icon and see the menu appear.  I have tried:

```
    #changeLayer:hover > #menu{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

But this does not work. When I just set the visibility of `#changeLayer` to visible, it appears on the screen, but the hover function for some reason does not work. I have tried changing the z-indexes, rearranging the order of the `div`s, but nothing happens.  Is this because it is using an image file and what might be a workaround?

CSS:

```
  #menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #fff;
    right: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#changeLayer{
  content:url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pixel-perfect-at-16px-volume-1/16/5049-512.png);
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
    top: 1%;
  left: 26%;
    height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    }

    #changeLayer:hover > #menu{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='changeLayer'></div>
<div id='menu'>
  <input id='bright' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='bright'>
  <label for='bright'>bright</label>
  <input id='light' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='light', checked='checked'>
  <label for='light'>light</label>
  <input id='dark' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='dark'>
  <label for='dark'>dark</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` is the child combinator selector. That will target children 1 layer deep that match your selector.

What you want to use instead is `+`, or the adjacent sibling selector, which will target the next element if it matches your selector.

This is a good article for reference - https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

```css
  #menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #fff;
    right: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  #changeLayer {
    content: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pixel-perfect-at-16px-volume-1/16/5049-512.png);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 1%;
    left: 26%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  
  #changeLayer:hover + #menu {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<div id='changeLayer'></div>
<div id='menu'>
  <input id='bright' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='bright'>
  <label for='bright'>bright</label>
  <input id='light' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='light', checked='checked'>
  <label for='light'>light</label>
  <input id='dark' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='dark'>
  <label for='dark'>dark</label>
</div>
```

The easiest way to keep `#menu` open after you hover `#changeLayer` is to wrap them both in an element, then use `:hover` on the parent element.

```css
  #menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #fff;
    right: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  #changeLayer {
    content: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pixel-perfect-at-16px-volume-1/16/5049-512.png);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 1%;
    left: 26%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  
  .wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .wrap:hover #menu {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div id='changeLayer'></div>
<div id='menu'>
  <input id='bright' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='bright'>
  <label for='bright'>bright</label>
  <input id='light' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='light', checked='checked'>
  <label for='light'>light</label>
  <input id='dark' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='dark'>
  <label for='dark'>dark</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Is there a way to keep  `#menu` open while it is being hover over as well?